# Connectivity of android microphone to handset via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am researching on the feasibility of the following Android app idea. Basic concept of the app is that a Bluetooth headset will be connected with the Android phone and as soon as the user opens the app the app will start listening from microphone and will start emitting to the handset which will be connected via Bluetooth. I have spent a lot of time on internet and could not find a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you are trying to achieve is not possible. You should learn how emitting and listening works on Android phones in general and via Bluetooth.